How to exclude an identity column from JOOQ code generation?
I have an identity column like below
alter table google_co2_emission_data
    add column co2_data_id bigint generated always as identity primary key;

I want to exclude co2_data_id from jooq code generation. By generator configuration looks like below
<generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
      <includes>.*</includes>
      <excludes>.*\.gossiper_update_v2 | .*\.kv_store | .*\.single_run_trigger | .*\.lease
        | .*\.gossiper_update_v2_checkpoint | .*\.google_co2_emission_data.co2_data_id
      </excludes>
      <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
    </database>
</generator>

I am still seeing code is being generated for google_co2_emission_data.co2_data_id. Is it possible to exclude an identity primary column from JOOQ code generation?

JOOQ Version - 3.17.16
Postgres - 14.4


Given your additional question, I don't think this is going to be the right approach as you will never have the ID value available, even for CRUD operations (UPDATE, DELETE), which seems wrong to me.

I used the same table structure in both the questions but the use case for this and that question is a bit different. Here I was looking for some way to hide the ID column (even for CRUD operations) from the Java side of the code.
Thanks, Lukas for answering both questions.

I see, all good then. Just wanted to make sure, because both questions were about omitting identities for some reason...

By default, the <includes> and <excludes> elements don't match columns, only schema objects. In order for it to match columns as well, use an additional <includeExcludeColumns/> flag. See also the documentation.
I.e.
<generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
      <includes>.*</includes>
      <excludes>
          .*\.gossiper_update_v2
        | .*\.kv_store
        | .*\.single_run_trigger
        | .*\.lease
        | .*\.gossiper_update_v2_checkpoint 
        | .*\.google_co2_emission_data.co2_data_id
      </excludes>
      <includeExcludeColumns>true</includeExcludeColumns>
      <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
    </database>
</generator>

